How to print garbage values in c using loop
When I run the following program it prints a garbage value:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}

But when I run this code that was intended for printing out ten garbage value is just printing zero one time. Why it is no longer showing any garbage value. I am using gcc compiler.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=0; i++) {
        int a;
        printf("%d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}

I expected this code to show ten different garbage values.

I expected this code to show ten different garbage values. why?

Why is 0 not a garbage value?

for (i=0; i<=0; i++) will not iterate ten times.

And technically, the value of uninitialized local non-static variables is indeterminate.

The result of invoking undefined behaviour is undefined.  Anything is possible; any result is as valid as any other.

Talk to your duck

(1) you are looping only once (from 0 to 0 included), (2) 0 is a perfectly valuable garbage value (3) more important reading an unitialized variable leads to undefined behaviour, from this point then anything is possible (as @JonathanLeffler stated).

Uninitialized variables are stored in special data segments, often called BSS. In the past, these areas were uninitialized and contained random values, or more precisely, whatever the previous program last wrote. For security reasons, these areas are now initialized by the loader, usually with zero, but also with other values. However, when programming, one should assume undefined values ​​and undefined behavior.

Out of curiosity, how frequently are such questions about C undefined variables asked on this site?

There is no value that is a “garbage value.” The phrase “garbage value” is a colloquialism that does not correctly describe the situation, and you should avoid using it.
When an object in C is not initialized, the C standard says it has an “indeterminate value.” Again, there is no value that is “indeterminate.” A better statement is that the value is not determined, meaning not only that no rule in the C standard specifies what the value should be but that the object does not even necessarily have a fixed value at all. Attempting to use the value of the object may produce different values at different times.
When the program prints “0”, that conforms with the rules of the C standard, because there is no requirement that any particular value be printed. When an indeterminate value is printed, any value of the type may be printed. Zero is a value of the type int, so it satisfies the criteria to be a so-called “indeterminate value” or “garbage value.“
The program prints only one value because for (i=0; i<=0; i++) iterates only one time. It sets i to zero, executes the body of the loop, and increments i to one. Then the test i<=0 is false, so the loop stops.
In this case, the entire behavior of your program is not defined because of a special rule that says using the value of an uninitialized object with automatic storage duration that could have been declared register has undefined behavior (C 2018 6.3.2.1 2). So the C standard does not require your program to print any value at all. It could crash or terminate without printing anything or print endless or do other things.

If I change the condition from i<=0 to i<=10 it prints zero ten times. Why the garbage value is always zero when I use a loop? It never returns zero as a garbage value when I write the program in such a way in which the variable declaration and printf statement is executed only once.

@CyberViperBarrack: That depends on the implementation details of your compiler. This behavior may change if you for example change the settings of the compiler, or if you update your compiler to a different version. If you really want an answer to that question, then you will have to study the assembly instructions that are emitted by your compiler.

@CyberViperBarrack: Whatever value is printed from an uninitialized object may be taken from memory the program would have used for the variable if it had been initialized or may be taken from a processor register or other places. Anytime you change the code in a program, such as when you insert a loop, that may change where in memory various things are placed. So the program may just happen to use a different location for the value, and different locations may have different data left over from the initialization work that starts your program.

the memory might just happen to be zerod out at that location, and the compiler might just be doing what you ask. its not uncommon for the stack to be zerod out, especially when youre trying this right at the start of the program
